# Estimating number of records in sql query after multiple inner joins

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 5 tables: Person,Table1,Table2,...Table4 and the query which I have to evaluate its cost in whatever method I wish.

```
select *
from Person P 
inner join
Table1 T1 on P.ID = T1.ID 
inner join
Table2 T2 on P.ID = T2.ID 
inner join
Table3 T3 on P.ID = T3.ID
inner join
Table2 T4 on P.ID = T4.ID
group by p.ID
```

The primary key of Person is ID, and each one of the other tables has a foreign key to Person.ID.

I also know the number of records in each table and that 90% of the persons in Person table appear in Table1

60% of the persons appear in Table2

70% of the persons appear in Table3

55% of the persons appear in Table4

(Duplicates of the persons are allowed in each one of Table1,...Table2)

I also have no data about which person is in which table/tables.

Now, after executing the inner-joins is there any method to estimate the total number of records in the relation created based on the data in order to calculate the cost of the sorting in the group by clause?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between 0% and 55%.  If you make the familiar statistical assumption that the values are independent, then you can calculate an estimate as:

```
0.9 * 0.60 * 0.70 * 0.55
```

which is about 20%.  However, independence is a pretty strong assumption.  Without knowledge of the underlying data and distributions, I'd still with the safe range of 0% - 55%.

In addition, this estimate is based on having at most one match in the "other" tables.  If you have multiple matches, then the estimate could, of course, explode.  And, you haven't mentioned the database you are using, but SQL databases do not necessarily sort the data for `group by`.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I have data about the number of records in each table. How exactly am I supposed to use the the expression 0.9 * 0.60 * 0.70 * 0.55? You mean that in each table the number of overlapping records according to this assumtion is 0.9 * 0.60 * 0.70 * 0.55*count(*)?

Comment: @OriLev . . . Your question is about the proportion of matching ids.  Other rows in the extra tables are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, using `COUNT(*)` runs in less than a minute and you will not have to use an estimate.

Since you're only evaluating `T1` to `T[N]` it's practically impossible to estimate the actual number of rows because we don't know the amount of overlap between `T2`, `T3` and `T4`.

The only real assumption we can make is that `T4`, with the 55% overlap is the maximum upper boundary using an `INNER JOIN`. Ultimately, using `INNER JOIN` the results will be between 0% of `T1` and 55% of `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query as sample to get the count and % of matching records

```
  SELECT   
  (t1.count(*)/p1.count(*))*100 as "t1%", 
   (t2.count(*)/p1.count(*))*100 as "t2%", 
   (t3.count(*)/p1.count(*))*100 as "t3%" 
  FROM 
  PERSON 
   P1 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1
  ON 
 P1.PERSONID=T1.PERSONID
 JOIN TABLE1 T2
  ON 
 P1.PERSONID=T2.PERSONID 
 JOIN TABLE3 T3 
  ON 
 P1.PERSONID=T3.PERSONID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find out the percentage based on **total persons** in `PERSON` table.

Your query will only consider the person which are included in relation(as `INNER JOIN` is used in your query) but what about other persons which is not included in the relation, means not in any of the listed table.

You need following query to find out the percentage:

```
SELECT   
  (count(DISTINCT T1.PERSONID)/count(DISTINCT P1.PERSONID))*100 AS T1_PRCENTAGE, 
  (count(DISTINCT T2.PERSONID)/count(DISTINCT P1.PERSONID))*100 AS T2_PRCENTAGE,
  (count(DISTINCT T3.PERSONID)/count(DISTINCT P1.PERSONID))*100 AS T3_PRCENTAGE,
  FROM 
  PERSON 
   P1 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1
  ON 
 P1.PERSONID=T1.PERSONID
 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T2
  ON 
 P1.PERSONID=T2.PERSONID 
 LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 
  ON 
 P1.PERSONID=T3.PERSONID;
```

I have used `LEFT JOIN` to consider **all the persons** from `PERSON` table which will be needed in counting the percentage.

Cheers!!